# fullpage.js: How to add class to next slide?

Tags: fullpage.js

I'm using `fullpage.js` and the scroll horizontal extension. I would like to add a `class` to the next slide which is then removed when that next slide becomes the **active** slide. Alternatively, I would like to add a class to all slides that are **inactive** (again, removing this `class` when the slides become **active**).

Anybody know how I can do this? Is there a way to use the `afterSlideLoad` callback?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fullpage.js already adds the class `active` to all active sections are slides.
You can read more about state classes added by fullPage.js [here in the docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#state-classes-added-by-fullpagejs).

Therefore, if what you need is to select those slides that are not active within a section using CSS you'll only need to do this:

```
.fp-section.active .fp-slide:not(.active)
```

In fact, you can use the same kind of selectors for Javascript:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.fp-section.active .fp-slide:not(.active)')
```